# What does 'homophilistic' mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I can't find it in any of respectable dictionaries. Instead,
I can only guess its meaning from the next sentence and with some knowledge in etymology(homo-'same';philo- 'love'). Is it a jargon like that?

> This distinction between strong and weak relationships was the
> centerpiece of one of the most influential studies in the social
> sciences in the last half century. Mark Granovetter examined the
> extent to which information about jobs flowed through weak versus
> strong ties among a group of people, in Amherst, Massachusetts.
> Granovetter found that only a sixth of jobs that came via the network
> were from strong ties, with the rest coming via medium or weak ties;
> and with more than a quarter coming via weak ties. Strong ties can be
> more ***homophilistic***. Our closest friends are often those who are
> most like us. This means that they might have information that is most
> relevant to us, but it also means that it is information to which we
> may already be exposed. In contrast, our weaker relationships are
> often with people who are more distant both geographically and
> demographically. Their information is less redundant. Even though we
> talk to these people less frequently, we have so many weak ties that
> they end up being a sizable source of information, especially of
> information to which we don’t otherwise have access.

[The Human Network: How Your Social Position Determines Your Power, Beliefs ...](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=X-4sDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=Strong%20ties%20can%20be%20more%20homophilistic.%20Our%20closest%20friends%20are%20often%20those%20who%20are%20most%20like%20us.%20This%20means%20that%20they%20might%20have%20information%20that%20is%20most%20relevant%20to%20us,%20but%20it%20also%20means%20that%20it%20is%20information%20to%20which%20we%20may%20already%20be%20exposed.&source=bl&ots=HA613T4jqf&sig=ACfU3U25Y03nf7npq6Lo3SZaw2cb3uGvSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj00JClr9f7AhWZqlYBHZ0aCB4Q6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=Strong%20ties%20can%20be%20more%20homophilistic.%20Our%20closest%20friends%20are%20often%20those%20who%20are%20most%20like%20us.%20This%20means%20that%20they%20might%20have%20information%20that%20is%20most%20relevant%20to%20us%2C%20but%20it%20also%20means%20that%20it%20is%20information%20to%20which%20we%20may%20already%20be%20exposed.&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

A quick search throws up several hits for [homophily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophily) and [homophilic](https://www.yourdictionary.com/homophilic). One of which is

> Tendency for people to maintain relationships with people who are
> similar to themselves, as characterized by age, race, gender,
> religion, or profession

Or as another put it "birds of a feather flock together"
A similar search for the suffix -istic shows that it is a way of making an adjective from a noun.